# Swing development in Netbeans vs JDeveloper

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdeveloper

I wrote a Java Swing app. using the JDeveloper IDE and I'd like to try converting it to the NetBeans IDE.  When I open the .java file in NetBeans it opens a text editor instead of the visual editor.  I noticed that if I create a new Swing .java file in NetBeans it opens that in a visual editor just fine.

The NetBeans Swing UI designer doesn't seem to be as friendly as the JDeveloper UI designer if NetBeans requires all the extra comments.

How can I convert the JDeveloper Swing .java file to a NetBeans Swing .java file automatically?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer - you can't.  See http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/import-jbuilder.html#faq

NetBeans is not an in-place GUI editor, instead, it has a resource file associated with each Java file that contains the actual GUI information.  The NetBeans Visual Designer needs this file to be able to perform the GUI development.

The only way of reliably using the NetBeans Visual Designer that I've found, was to recreate the GUI in NetBeans. Every single import / conversion tool I've used created messy code that was difficult to maintain and near impossible to edit. It also introduced problems in my GUI that I didn't have before.

NetBeans Visual Designer is a great tool, but only if you start out in it. Create a new GUI form in NetBeans and then look in the source folder for the related files, they will have a .form extension and is in an XML format.